# Windows 10 Cortana/Search Turned White

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, colors, cortana

I recently got the April update for Windows 10 and immediately I noticed Cortana/Search on the taskbar sticking out like a sore thumb.

The seemingly only valid solution available is to turn the app mode to dark via the color settings.

Others have been able to find temporary solutions that revert back once the system is rebooted (which I do every day).

I don't need a white Cortana/Search box, I just want what I had.

Adding to that, I don't want my app mode "theme" to be dark. I want those UAC dialogue boxes to be white, not black.

Also, they couldn't have implemented this crap so inconsistently.

How is it that some menus/dialogue boxes turn up black but File Explorer is still white?

Does anyone have a fix? AFAIK, there's only one registry tweak that some folk have been messing with but I don't see those particular values/keys in my registry.

**TL;DR**:
I'm more than willing to tweak with my registry so long as Cortana/Search bar in taskbar reverts to the color it was before (not white) and my app mode theme isn't dark.

**EDIT** (11/19/2018):
I am running Windows 10 Pro v. 1803.

**EDIT #2**:
The solution cannot be to simply "turn off" the search bar and replace with icon. That doesn't change the color of the search box. The objective is to revert the color of the box to its original color and keep it matching with the taskbar color. The solution cannot also be to turn the "app mode" dark. I want to keep my app mode white, thereby keeping settings windows and UAC windows white, but I want the search box to be the default grayish-blue.

**EDIT #3**:
1703 Solutions that worked but no longer work permanently:

1) https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/97220-cortana-search-field-color-changing-default-gray-white-post1197520.html#post1197520

2) https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/86467-cortana-search-box-changed-white-color.html
The above threads mention the registry hack which is now obsolete and one of the two popular "work arounds" that sort of worked before. The other which is not mentioned is downloading/running a .BAT file and allowing it to alter something on its own. That method didn't work in the long run or simply wasn't a perfect solution (i.e. bugs).

Comment: Could you list, or give a link to, the registry hacks that don't work any more?

Comment: @harrymc Yep, I'll do that now. Give me 5-min.